# MalformedURLException in java application

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, imageicon

i wrote a simple program which is in my book.
but i'm getting the MalformedURLException exception.This is my code

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ImageGreet{
    public static void main(String []args){
        URL imageLocation = new URL("http://horstmann.com/java4everyone/duke.gif");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hello","Title",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,new ImageIcon(imageLocation));
    }
}
```

but my friend said he got it right with the same code.
what's wr9ong with my code? Is it because of the internet connection(I'm using a dial-up connection)
I

Comment: Simply creating a URL object does not connect to a network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Java has checked exception you have to add throws MalformedURLException to your methods header or you have to write the method logic inside try/catch blocks.

Answer (score 3):

Java uses the concept of `checked Exceptions`. You need to put this code inside a `try/catch` block, since it is bound to throw a `MalformedURLException`. Something like

```
URL imageLocation = null;
try {
    imageLocation = new URL("http://horstmann.com/java4everyone/duke.gif");
} catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
    mue.printStackTrace();
}
```

Or let the `main` method `throws` the `Exception` like :

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ImageGreet{
    public static void main(String []args) throws MalformedURLException {
        URL imageLocation = new URL("http://horstmann.com/java4everyone/duke.gif");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hello","Title",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,new ImageIcon(imageLocation));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

catch the MalformedURLException using try and catch block

```
 try {
    URL imageLocation = new URL("http://horstmann.com/java4everyone/duke.gif");
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hello","Title",
JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,new        ImageIcon(imageLocation));
    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
        // new URL() failed
        // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your internet connection would not cause that Exception. (If your URL did not exist, Java would throw an IOException, probably a FileNotFoundException, per [URLConnection documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect%28%29).) In fact, your code isn't throwing an Exception at all! What you're seeing is a compile error:

```
$ javac ImageGreet.java
ImageGreet.java:7: error: unreported exception MalformedURLException; must be caught or  declared to be thrown
        URL imageLocation = new URL("http://horstmann.com/java4everyone/duke.gif");
                            ^
1 error
```

When Java tries to turn your program from source code into machine code, it finds a problem, so it stops and asks you to fix it. Your code hasn't run yet -- Java's warning you that there's a problem with your program's source code. (If you're running an IDE, this will show up in a "problems" pane, as opposed to an error message from javac.)

The issue is that you need to catch the MalformedURLException in your code, or declare that `main` throws MalformedURLException. For example:

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ImageGreet{
    public static void main(String []args) throws MalformedURLException {
        URL imageLocation=new URL("http://horstmann.com/java4everyone/duke.gif");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hello","Title",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,new ImageIcon(imageLocation));
    }
}
```

Note that I've added `throws MalformedURLException` to the end of your main method, which is the latter of the solutions I suggested above. That tells Java that your main method may propagate an Exception of type MalformedURLException.